# Issue running Android Studio emulator: git set up launches and tries to downgrade

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter, path, emulation

I am currently working on a flutter application using Android Studio. When I try to run the file or use the emulator, the Git set up prompt appears. I have git installed to the latest version (Git 2.30.0.2), but the set up prompt tries to install an older version:

```
Git for Windows 2.30.0.2 is currently installed. Do you really want to downgrade to Git for Windows 2.14.1?
```

A few days ago Android Studio was working fine and now I have this issue. I assume it might have something to do with Android Studio not being able to find the git location (so it might be an issue with the git path).

Even so, I don't know how that could be possible. This problem showed up suddenly, I had already ran the emulator multiple times on a project (let's call it Project 1) and it worked fine. When I tried to load another project (Project 2) the git set up prompt appeared. When I went back to run Project 1, I had the same issue there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that error message in [`git-for-windows/build-extra` `installer/install.iss`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/installer/install.iss#L1016-L1033)

It pops up just after querying the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
'Software\GitForWindows',
'CurrentVersion',
PreviousGitForWindowsVersion
```

And when the [IsDowngrade(CurrentVersion:String):Boolean](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/installer/install.iss#L915-L934) somehow return true because the current version from the registry is different from the current one.

Forcing the previous version to be empty would side-step this issue.

Comment: if I were to uninstall previous git versions and just keep the most recent one, would that work? If not how do you suggest I force the previous Gits to become empty?

Comment: @ThéodoreTremblot Yes, I would only keep the current one. Personally, I never install Git, I only unzip the portable archive. That way, I can have as many Git version I want without any issue.